Crystal oscillator based on a differential pair of npn transistors does not oscillate
I do not know if the input or output gain of my circuit in the differential pair is the error so that it does not oscillate. I even tried with a small pulse so that my circuit starts to oscillate.


You appear to be missing a connection at the collector of Q2. The wires cross but there’s no connection dot. Without this connection there’s no feedback through the crystal.
Also there is no voltage to the collector resistors of Q1 and Q2.
And there’s no DC bias for the base of Q2.
There may be other problems but there are a couple of obvious ones to get you started. Go back over your schematic and check it for simple mistakes like that, once you’ve got the schematic correct you can deal with any problems in the simulation settings.

after rechecking I realized that I missed to feed the Q1 and Q2 and their respective resistors with the 5V source and I made the correct connection of Q2 and my resistor, but still my oscillator did not work, what would be the small adjustments in my simulation that would help me? I am very lost at that point.

@KevinWhite - Thanks for trying to help but it's too late to change the schematic. This answer explains the issues with the original schematic. If the schematic is changed, it makes this answer look wrong! Please search for the term "chameleon question" on Meta.SE for discussions explaining the issues with chameleon questions. || Stack Exchange aims to have question & answer pairs. If the question gets changed so that answer(s) no longer match the question, that goes against the SE methodology. I'm deleting the change suggestion.

@EstebanLan - Hi, As I just commented, it's too late to change the schematic in this question, since doing that means the issues raised in the answer here no longer apply. || It leads to a situation where answer X applies to question rev 1. After the question is changed, later answer Y applies to the different schematic in question rev 2. Then the schematic gets changed again and later answer Z applies to question rev 3. Which one answer (you can only choose one) becomes the accepted answer? They were all correct for the schematic at the time they were written,

{...} but answers X&Y look wrong at the end :( This is why "chameleon questions" which change the question after answers were written, break the Stack Exchange approach. You can find posts discussing "chameleon questions" on the main [meta.se]. I have reversed your change to the question. || If you still have questions about an improved / fixed schematic, then you can ask a new complete, standalone question, if needed. Include a link back to this question for context. Explain the changes you have made, why, and the problem with the new schematic. TY

(And before someone says that answers should be updated by their authors to match the moving goalposts of a question. No, there is no expectation for answer-writers to have to commit to a never-ending series of answer updates, to keep up with a changing question.)

The basic idea will be something like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
It's not a complete design and I used \$5\:\text{V}\$ here. (I'd recommend keeping the \$10\,\text{mA}\$ current sink but adjust the biasing as appropriate for other rail voltages.)
The duty cycle won't be a perfect 50%.
Using very low Q, only 2000 for this example, LTspice shows this (the outputs are taken from the two collectors):

(Higher Q works well, of course.)
This would not be a final design. If for no other reason then because the output likely needs buffering before it drives some other circuit. But it is a demonstration of the behavioral topology to use as a basis.

You're loading the output with Q3. Remove Q3 and the parts it connects to. Start simple. No point in adding the load if the oscillator won't oscillate without the load.
The pulse node is connected to a voltage source. That means that the oscillator will never oscillate. But it's maybe hard to notice because you have not drawn the full schematic. You have a partial schematic, and a partial netlist. This "label connection" business makes it hard for you to notice things. It's OK for supply voltages, not ok for much else. For a beginner I'd suggest not even doing it for the supply voltages. Just draw everything out and lay it our neatly.
The crystal needs to be connected between the collector of Q1 and base of Q2.
